# Can Outlook calander be set as default in Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I discussed with Samsung if Outlook Calendar can be set as default calendar in Samsung Galaxy S7. Their response is that the Google calendar has to be the default calendar. I use Office 365 and would like the functionality provided using the Outlook calendar in an Exchange environment. Does anyone have a work around? I'd like to be able to use Google Voice to record events to the Outlook Calendar.(in's convenient when I'm driving)